# Error Lag function

Tags: r

I have the following vector which is autocorrelated and functions (package **quantmod**)

```
### rm(list=ls())
s <- filter(rnorm(100), filter=rep(1,3), circular=TRUE)
a <- acf(s)
b <- a[[1]] 
c <- (b[2:length(b)])
posssignificance_level <- qnorm((1+0.90)/2)/sqrt(sum(!is.na(s)))
negsignificance_level <- -posssignificance_level
poscorr <- which(posssignificance_level<c)
negcorr <- which(negsignificance_level>c)
```

Using `negcorr` and `poscorr` different coefficients in each I would like to produce a number of columns with the lag/s I obtained by `poscorr` and `negcorr`. I do

```
posautorrelation  <- Lag(s, poscorr)
negautorrelation  <- Lag(s, negcorr)
```

However I obtain the following error mesagge for both

```
Error en `tsp<-`(`*tmp*`, value = p - (k/p[3L]) * c(1, 1, 0)) : 
el atributo 'tsp' debe ser numérico de longitud tres
Además: Mensajes de aviso perdidos
1: In if (k != round(k)) { :
la condición tiene longitud > 1 y sólo el primer elemento será usado
2: In (k/p[3L]) * c(1, 1, 0) :
longitud de objeto mayor no es múltiplo de la longitud de uno menor
3: In p - (k/p[3L]) * c(1, 1, 0) :
longitud de objeto mayor no es múltiplo de la longitud de uno menor
Error durante el wrapup: no se puede abrir la conexión
```

Would you happen to know why is the error ocurring and what expression would I have to use as to produce the columns for posautorrelation and negautorelation

Comment: I have and there is no integer(O), s produces a random series and the poscorr and negcorr are fine as far as I can see

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### tl;dr

There is no `Lag()` method for class `"ts"`, hence it dispatches to the base function `lag()` which doesn't like the vector of `k` lags being passed here. A solution is to force the use of the `Lag.numeric()` method or coerce the time series `s` to one of the supported classes; `"numeric"` or `"zoo"` for example.

### Detail

The problem is that the default method for `Lag()` dispatches to `lag()` and from what I can tell, it expects only to have a single lag `k` provided. If you follow this down, you will see a line in `stats:::lag.default` which computes

```
tsp(x) <- p - (k/p[3L]) * c(1, 1, 0)
```

where `p` is the `tsp()` of the input data, `k` is the lag. When you pass in a vector of K > 1 lags k, you get this:

```
R> p - (poscorr/p[3L]) * c(1, 1, 0)
[1]  0 98  1
Warning message:
In (poscorr/p[3L]) * c(1, 1, 0) :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

(for example using some of your data).

Next note that `'tsp<-'()` sets the `"tsp"` attribute of its argument vector `x` via

```
attr(x, "tsp") <- value
```

and if you debug down far enough you'll find this is the line raising the Error. If we read `?attr` we see that the `"tsp"` attributes are handled as a special case

```
 Note that some attributes (namely ‘class’, ‘comment’, ‘dim’,
 ‘dimnames’, ‘names’, ‘row.names’ and ‘tsp’) are treated specially
 and have restrictions on the values which can be set.  (Note that
 this is not true of ‘levels’ which should be set for factors via
 the ‘levels’ replacement function.)
```

and it is from the C code that we must go looking for why the error is raised. If we skip that bit, we can just infer that

```
R> p - (poscorr/p[3L]) * c(1, 1, 0)
[1]  0 98  1
```

are not valid for the time series `s` supplied to `Lag()` originally.

A work around is simply to call a more appropriate `Lag()` method directly. There is a `"numeric"` method, but for that to work you need to convert `s` to a numeric vector, al call the `"numeric"` method directly:

```
quantmod:::Lag.numeric(s, poscorr)

R> head(quantmod:::Lag.numeric(s, poscorr))
       Lag.1   Lag.2
[1,]      NA      NA
[2,] -1.5363      NA
[3,] -0.2461 -1.5363
[4,] -0.3276 -0.2461
[5,] -0.8280 -0.3276
[6,] -0.2980 -0.8280
```

or by coercion

```
Lag(as.numeric(s), poscorr)

R> head(Lag(as.numeric(s), poscorr))
       Lag.1   Lag.2
[1,]      NA      NA
[2,] -1.5363      NA
[3,] -0.2461 -1.5363
[4,] -0.3276 -0.2461
[5,] -0.8280 -0.3276
[6,] -0.2980 -0.8280
```

The latter being the preferred way here. You can also coerce to a `"zoo"` class object:

```
Lag(as.zoo(s), poscorr)

R> head(Lag(as.zoo(s), poscorr))
    Lag.1   Lag.2
1      NA      NA
2 -1.5363      NA
3 -0.2461 -1.5363
4 -0.3276 -0.2461
5 -0.8280 -0.3276
6 -0.2980 -0.8280
```

`Lag()` should probably catch this and bail out if vector `k` is going to be passed to `lag()`. Or it could `sapply()` over the `k` for multiple `lag()` calls, as it does in the `"numeric"` case.

Comment: Understood and thank you for your detailed reply, it was beyond my reach. I will follow through the conversion to numeric which seems to work.